# use zsh's built in pager instead of less

Tags: shell, unix, zsh, less-unix

Suppose I've got a giant command

```
echo "start string `complexcommand -with -many args | cut -d ' ' -moreargs | sed 's/you/get/g' | grep -v "the idea" | xargs echo` ending string" | program | less -S
```

It produces output of several hundred lines of many thousand characters in length.

`less` handles scrolling vertically quite well, as that's what it is used for most of the time, but scrolling left and right is very CPU taxing according to `top` and I am not aware of any "page-left" or "page-right" style commands to go faster.

So I'm hoping that something like zsh's built-in pager could handle this task faster, but I'm having trouble figuring out the command to use it. It takes a file input. Is there a way to make a oneliner use the pager rather than having to dump it to a file first?

Or if anybody has suggestions for better editors. I might try using vim next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to invoke zsh's pager, use `some-complex-pipeline | zsh -c '< /dev/fd/0'`.  The /dev/fd/0 file is a device that represents the current process's standard input stream.

Comment: oh okay. I hadn't tried that approach. thanks. Will accept when I get around to testing this on my humongous input

Comment: I wish I wrote down what that "humongous input" was. Oh past me is so mysterious -- **edit:** Oh! It was printing SQL table dumps :D I was all, when the hell has less let me down? - Oh hey thats right, when I tried to feed it **that** so that I could filter some regexps on it -- now i guess if less or zsh (or bash!) couldn't handle it, surely `Vim 7.4.BETA14` could.

Comment: Is there a way to exit only on 'q' instead of exiting upon reaching EOF?